# Why are my parameters always passed as null to my OnPost method?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I've got a simple function that receives a string representing the binary data of a PDF file, a filename string and an integer employee ID.

This is the function:

```
public JsonResult OnPostSavePDFStatement(string pdfData, string filename, int employeeId)
{
    pdfData = pdfData.Replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", "");
    var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(pdfData);

    DL.SavePDFStatement(filename, employeeId, User.Identity.Name, fileContents);

    return new JsonResult(new { result = true });
}
```

The problem is all the parameters, `pdfData`, `filename`, and `employeeId` always as passed as null.

I'm using jQuery to send the data to the server:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Statement/MyStatementsPDF?handler=SavePDFStatement",
            data: formData,
            content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function (response)
            {
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log('Error saving PDF to DB');
            }
        });
```

I've verified client side that formData is populated correctly. I've used fiddler to inspect what's sent to the server and can see all three parameters populated. Is there somewhere in the pipeline where I can set a breakpoint and walkthrough .NET's attempt to bind what's being sent over to the parameters and see where/why it's failing?

EDIT -- I tried removing the pdfData parameter and sure enough, then employeeId and filename come through fine. Something about the presence of the pdfData in the payload makes the binding fail.

Comment: if you use a new FormData object, it'll set the content-type and stream the file...  no need for Base64 encoding there...  so remove the "content: "application/json; charset=utf-8", bit and bind to a File in your controller.  Ex:  [BindProperty]
 public IFormFile PDFFile { get; set; }

Comment: @browsermator I'm not sure I can do that. I'm using kendo to convert the DOM to a PDF and the data is handed to me as a base64 encoded string. The problem seems to be one of length. The PDF data is 9.7MB. If I cut the base64 string to a quarter that size it comes through. Do you know where that length limit would be set and can I adjust it?

Comment: should be something like: services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue); https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.formoptions.valuelengthlimit?view=aspnetcore-6.0  or builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue); In program.cs