# How to send a complex object with images to .net Core 8 server with javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-8

I'm trying to understand what is the best approach to sending the following object to a asp.NET 8 core web application. It is not a web api, just a normal website accepting a complex object input. Here is the object I am referring to:

```
public class ComponentModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String SomeOtherValuesLikeThis { get; set; }
    public IList<ElementModel> Elements { get; set; } = new List<ProductComponentElementModel>();
}

public class ElementModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String SomeOtherValuesLikeThis { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

Normally I would do an ajax call which would allow me to send the complex object in form of json and that would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Some/Uri",
    type: "POST",
    data: myComplexObjectBuiltInJavascript,
    success: function (response) {
        //Do Some Logic
    },
    error: function (error) {
        //Throw an error
    },
    complete: function () {
        //Do Something
    }
});
```

However, because my ElementModel has a IFormFile I now have to send this object as a FormData (at least to my understanding, correct me if I am wrong). Something like this:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("Id", SomeId);
```

As the above is a linear build, I am failing to understand how do I turn this into a complex object, is this even possible? If not, what is another way I can send a complex object like above to my server with potentially multiple files.

If this is simply not possible or this is bad practice for some reason, how do you suggest that I send this complex data to my server?

So far I have thought of two approaches:

1. Split into two types of calls, first call the parent to ensure the parent record is created, then second call for children (but this would result in many calls unless there is a way to do an array object that contains images and other fields).
2. upload the complex object as is, then do a second call with images only and some way to reference where they belong.

The above ideas result in partial creation which I don't like, means a lot of cleanup if the subsequent calls fail. Right now I am leaning towards method 2 as a result of this as it feels less messy.

How should I approach this?

Note: If you provide an answer, please try to use code examples to help me better understand.

Comment: what even is `myComplexObjectBuiltInJavascript`?

Comment: You can't really send JavaScript objects to the server, at least not real JavaScript objects. You can send JavaScript as a string or JSON or serialized to a `TypedArray` using `TextEncoder`, both directly and using a `FormData` object.

Comment: _"upload the complex object as is, then do a second call with images only and some way to reference where they belong."_ All of your data can be posted to the server in a single `FormData` object, or in a single `Blob`, or if you prefer, serialized to JSON, including images, text, etc.

Comment: @guest271314 how would I do that? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Just append your serialized data as JSON or a `TypedArray`, a string (JSON is a string format, too),  to the `FormData`. A `Blob` or `File` is particularly useful in this case. You can write a string, number, JSON, `TypedArray`, images, and so forth to a single `Blob`, then extract the data - as long as you keep track of offsets. Right now I have no idea what `myComplexObjectBuiltInJavascript` is.

Comment: @guest271314 OH! I see what you mean. pass everything as a single string and attach all images in formdata and then sort them on server side. Didn't think of that. I think I like that approach the most as then I can control data saving a lot easier.

Comment: Here is an example of including a `Uint32Array` (the length of the following variable length JSON configuration which contains offsets of the included data), JSON configuration, optionally image, artist, album data for Media Session API, and Opus packets produced by WebCodecs `AudioEncoder` to a `Blob` downloaded as a single file. Using those offsets in the JSON configuration I am able to extract the images, artists, album data for Media Session API, and play back those Opus packets in the browser - https://github.com/guest271314/WebCodecsOpusRecorder/blob/main/WebCodecsOpusRecorder.js#L85-L87

Comment: If you are also responsible for .Net core code
 - Keep current ajax call which allows you to send object in form of json as it is.
 - instead **IFormFile** use **string** and send image file as **Base64**
 - on server convert **Base64** back to image

Comment: imo, formdata is the best way to go... just use new FormData(form_element);  That'll stream the file and you won't need to blowup the file size by base64 encoding it. Otherwise you will probably need to adjust some settings in ASP.NET for form length limits.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77964698/why-are-my-parameters-always-passed-as-null-to-my-onpost-method#comment137448256_77964698